# FFMPEG Scan and Convert Movie files and Delete Original - reclusively

Tags: ffmpeg, terminal

I have folders within folders that have movie files, some of them are .mp4, .avi or .mov/.MOV. I need to re-compress them into H264 High Quality (Lets say, 10MBPS) and delete the originals when complete. I have the following code, but this is for audio and I don't know where to go from here. I am using Mac terminal.

`for i in *.ogg; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -b:a 320000 "${i%.*}.mp3"; done`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example on how this can convert mp4 files to 10M h264 files, which can be easily modified and run again for other file types,and can be easily modified to remove files after they have been converted:

```
convert_file() {

    # loop through all mp4 files in current directory
    for i in $1*.mp4;
        # convert to .h264
        do ffmpeg -i "$i" -b:v 10M -b:a 192k -an -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 "${i%.*}.h264" -y
    done

    # recursive call
    # call convert_file function for each sub directory
    for d in $1*/; do
        if [ -d "$d" ]
        then
            convert_file $d; 
        fi 
    done
}
# call with path/to/myvideos
convert_file ~/Videos/
```